# How do i delete a pointer from an abstract class

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm new to C++ and CS in general. I am having trouble understanding how to fully prevent memory leaks.
I have an abstract class called shape and I set a pointer using the abstract class. However, when I try and delete the pointer, I still find memory leaks.
When checking with valgrind, I get this message

```
==14227== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14227==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==14227==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 73,760 bytes allocated
==14227== 
==14227== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14227==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14227==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14227==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14227==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==14227==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14227== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory 
==14227==
```

shape.hpp

```
class Shape
{
 protected:
     int sides;
     int length;
     int width

 public:
     virtual int perimeter() = 0;
     virtual int area() = 0;
     virtual ~Shape(){}
};
```

rectangle.hpp

```
class Rectangle : public Shape
{
 public:
     Rectangle();
     virtual int perimeter();
     virtual int area();
     void setLength(int);
     void setWidth(int);
     int getLength();
};
```

rectangle.cpp

```
Rectangle::Rectangle()
{
 setLength(2);
 setWidth(5);
}

void Rectangle::setLength(int l)
{length = l;}

void Rectangle::setWidth(int w)
{width = w}

int Rectangle::perimeter()
{enter code here}

int Rectangle::area()
{enter code here}

int Rectangle::getLength()
{return length;}
```

main.cpp

```
Shape *s1;

int main()
{
 s1 = new Rectangle();

 cout << "Length: " << s1->getLength() << endl;

 delete s1;

 return 0;

 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but couldn't that be a false positive? Try to move either the s1 pointer into the main function or set it explicitly to 0.

Comment: Valgrind's message explicitly states that it didn't detect a memory leak

Comment: 0 bytes are indicated as lost. The "still reachable" just correspond to the heap summary.

Comment: As said in my answer, I *really* wonder if you are executing the code you believe. I do not see how `new Rectangle ()` can compile if the constructor is private as in the code you pasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good, you edited your question so as the Rectangle constructor is public. Otherwise it siimply could not have compiled.

You correctly define the Shape destructor as virtual.
And you consequently delete the Shape pointer.

I'm not used to Valgrind, (I was C++ Windows dev)
Are you sure Valgrind is talking about a pointer to your Shape object ?

Can you list the pointer value that is still allocated in Valgrind ?
Maybe checking its memory content would assure you it is not your object that is causing this allocation.

**EDIT:**
One trick you can do, if you don't know how to step-by-step debug with gdb, you do:

```
virtual ~Rectangle()
{
   std::cout << " proof the destructor has been called";
}
```

If you do see the trace in the output, then you'll question Valgrind diagnostic, and not your code.

Comment: sorry! I was manually typing everything out. I changed the access variable to public

Comment: but does it reflect the code you are really compiling and executing.

Comment: yes, this is the code I am really trying to compile and execute. I was just manually typing out the code

Comment: I have added an EDIT I advise you to follow. It will prove your destructor is called.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion about the leak summary.

Valgrind is stating that it has found no memory leaks:

```
==14227== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14227==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14227==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14227==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

The following line `==14227==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks` just highlights the heap usage when the program is exited.